# is $f(S) =(|S|)^2$ submodular?

Tags: optimization

I am working on an optimization problem for my graduate research. I would like to know whether the square of the cardinality of a set is submodular or not.

Thank you in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $f(\{1,2\})+f(\emptyset) > f(\{1\})+f(\{2\})$.

In general, if $f(S)=g(|S|)$, then $f$ is supermodular if $g$ is concave and submodular if $g$ is convex.

Comment: Thank you very much. That's a concise, simple example.